# Given a python dictionary, most efficient means to extract keys that start with a string pattern

Tags: python

Lets say I have a python dictionary:

```
{'i:crid1':1, 'c:crid1':1, 'i:crid2':1, 'c:crid2':1....}
```

What is the most elegant way in python to just extract all keys that begin with c:?

```
{'c:crid1':1,'c:crid2':1....}
```

Speed is of the utmost importance and can be a big dict.  Maybe weave is a candidate tool.

I added this comment.  The dicts come from redis.  No choice about the data structure... that being said.  I need speed.  Not elegance.

Comment: elegance and speed are often conflicting requirements. which is it?

Comment: Best solution: don't use this data structure. You want something like a trie if you're going to use prefixes of the keys.

Comment: Are those `c:` xml namespaces?

Comment: Elegance is a matter of opinion. Speed is not.

Comment: If you're going to be doing *many* of these prefix extractions on *one* dict that comes from redis, you can still win by creating the dict-of-dicts structure I suggested in my answer as soon as you get the big dict. If not, the other answers are more relevant.

Answer (score 3):

If speed is of the *utmost* importance, you probably want to build a dict of dicts in the first place, where the outer dict is indexed by the prefix:

```
dd = {'i':{ 'i:crid1':1, 'i:crid2':1 }, 'c':{'c:crid1':1, 'c:crid2':1 } }
```

If space is no object and you sometimes want the whole dict rather than a prefix subset, you can build both the one-big-dict and the dict-of-dict versions side by side; otherwise it's not hard to build it on the fly when you need it.

Comment: Yeah, provided you have control over how this dictionary is built in the first place, this seems like the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using a dict comprehension is both fast and concise, although a dict doesn't seem quite appropriate in the first place if speed is really a concern:

```
>>> d = {'i:crid1':1, 'c:crid1':1, 'i:crid2':1, 'c:crid2':1 }
>>> { k:v for k,v in d.iteritems() if k.startswith('c:') }
{'c:crid2': 1, 'c:crid1': 1}
```

Or, if you are on Python before 2.7:

```
>>> dict((k, v) for k,v in d.iteritems() if k.startswith('c:'))
{'c:crid2': 1, 'c:crid1': 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> d = {'i:crid1': 1, 'c:crid1': 1, 'i:crid2': 1, 'c:crid2': 1}
>>> %timeit dict((k, v) for k, v in d.iteritems() if k.startswith('c:'))
    # 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.12 us per loop
>>> import re
>>> patt = re.compile('^c:.')
>>> %timeit dict((k, v) for k, v in d.iteritems() if patt.match(k))
    # 100000 loops, best of 3: 5.22 us per loop
>>> { k:v for k,v in d.iteritems() if k.startswith('c:') }
    # 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.22 us per loop
```

Comment: Why is the dict comprehension so much faster than passing a generator expression to the dict constructor?

Comment: `k[:2]=='c:'` may be faster than using `startswith`

Comment: Nice thought @gnibbler but it hovers around the 4.0 us mark like .startswith(); No usefully discernable difference.

Comment: @Rob, sure, but this is for a small dict. The OP mentions that the real dicts will be large - maybe it makes more difference then.

Answer (score 1):

For python versions < 2.7 where you don't have dict comprehensions, you can use

```
>>> d = {'i:crid1':1, 'c:crid1':1, 'i:crid2':1, 'c:crid2':1 }
>>> dict((k, v) for k,v in d.iteritems() if k.startswith('c:'))
{'c:crid2': 1, 'c:crid1': 1}
```

To only extract the keys, you can use

```
(k for k in d.iterkeys() if k.startswith('c:'))
```

and iterate over it.